# Play 2.2.1 - JavaWS - How to override the connection Idle Timeout

Tags: playframework

I have web service which takes almost 3 minutes and this service is called using WS -Async. 
Play's default connection idle period  is minutes. After 2 minutes it throws an exception saying "Request reached idle time out of 120000 ms after 120007 ms" . So i am unable to get my promise result. 
So, is there any was i can increase the connection idle timeout span in play 2.2.1?

Comment: I'd suggest that you include your code, as this will enable people to answer your question better

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to configure the timeout in `application.conf` using

```
# Value is milliseconds, so the following represents 4 minutes
ws.timeout = 240000
```

You can find other possible configurations in [ScalaWS documentation - Configuring WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS)

Answer (score 1):

```
WSRequestHolder req = WS.url("whatever");
req.setTimeout(120000*2);
Promise<WSResponse> resp=req.get();
```

If you want to apply that timeout for every request, add this to the application.conf: `ws.timeout=240000`

All this is available in the [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaWS)